# Calculation of integral with different roots

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I am supposed to calculate integral:$$\int \frac{4x+5\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt[3]{\left ( x+2 \right )^{2}}}dx$$ but I do not know, how to use the substitution.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by “different roots”?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I mean when there are different powers of roots, if is there any rule how to substitute them (e.g. take the common multiple of them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting $$t=\sqrt{x+2}$$ we get $$dx=2tdt$$ and $$\sqrt[3]{(t+2)^2}=t^{4/3}$$ so we get
$$2\int\frac{4t^2+5t-8}{t^{1/3}}dt$$ This is equal to
$$2\int 4t^{5/3}+5t^{2/3}-8t^{-1/3}dt$$

Comment: how did you get $$2.\int \frac{4t^{2}+5t-8}{\sqrt[3]{t}}dt$$ ?

Comment: From $$t=\sqrt{x+2}$$ we get $$x=t^2-8$$

Comment: I understand numerator, but do not understand denominator

Comment: And $$dx=2tdt$$

Comment: And $$(x+2)^2=t^4$$ so $$\sqrt[3]{(x+2)^2}=t^{4/3}$$

Comment: Okay, now I understand it.. thanks.. but Is not there any rule, which says that in such a cases there should be any substitution made by the highest power of roots?

Comment: There is no rule my Prof told me it is better to substitute the square root.

Comment: okay, thanks you so much

Comment: Have a nice evening, but not to hot, like in Germany.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may write
\begin{align}
\frac{4x+5\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt[3]{\left ( x+2 \right )^{2}}}&=\frac{4x+8-8}{\sqrt[3]{\left ( x+2 \right )^{2}}}+\frac{5\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt[3]{\left ( x+2 \right )^{2}}}
\\\\&=(x+2)^{1/3}-\frac{8}{(x+2)^{2/3}}+\frac{5}{(x+2)^{1/6}}
\end{align} then just perform the change of variable $t=x+2$.

Comment: okay, thank you